# Adding to a message for various errors on form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am attempting to make a form where if information is not input, you get a series of error messages depending on what's not there. Unfortunately, I've run into an issue where the variable Msg that holds the messages is not working (Will make sense in a moment I think). It does display the errors, but in a paragraph form, not in a list.

How can I compile all errors into a message with line breaks?

I've tried to include "\n" and "\r\n" to no avail.

What I have now is this:

```
Msg = Msg + "Text goes here for error messages...";
```

Code:

```
       private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//DECLARATIONS
        int count = 0;
        string Msg = "";
        Boolean validatedState = true;
        Boolean validateEntry = false;
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2016, 03, 01);
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2016, 03, 01);

//BEGIN SERIES OF IF/ELSE FOR CONFIRMING ENTRIES         
        if (Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            //displays yellow bg for missing input
            txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            Msg = Msg + "Please Enter a First Name" + "\r\n";
        }//endif
        else
        {
            txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; 
            count += 1;
        }//end else

        if (Request["txtLastName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            //displays yellow bg for missing input
            txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            Msg = Msg + "Please Enter a Last Name";
        }//endif
        else
        {
            txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; 
            count += 1;
        }//end else

        if (Request["txtPayRate"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            //displays yellow bg for missing input
            txtPayRate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            Msg = Msg + "Please Enter a Pay Rate";
         }//endif
        else
        {
            txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; 
            count += 1;
        }//end else

        if (Request["txtStartDate"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            //displays yellow bg for missing input
            txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            validateEntry = false;
            Msg = Msg + "Please Enter a Start Date";
        }//endif
        else
        {
            startDate = DateTime.Parse(Request["txtStartDate"]);
            validateEntry = true;
        }//end else

        if (Request["txtEndDate"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            //displays yellow bg for missing input
            txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            validateEntry = false;
            Msg = Msg + "Please Enter an End Date";
         }//endif
        else
        {
            endDate = DateTime.Parse(Request["txtEndDate"]);
            validateEntry = true;
        }//end else
//END SERIES OF IF/ELSE FOR CONFIRMING ENTRIES 

//START IF VALIDATE ENTRY    
        if (validateEntry == true)
        {
            if (DateTime.Compare(startDate, endDate) >= 0)
            {
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                Msg = Msg + "The end date must be a later date than the start date.";
                //The Msg text will be displayed in lblError.Text after all the error messages are concatenated
                validatedState = false;
                //Boolean value - test each textbox to see if the data entered is valid, if not set validState=false. 
                //If after testing each validation rule, the validatedState value is true, then submit to frmPersonnelVerified.aspx, if not, then display error message
                Response.Write("<span style= 'BackColor:red'>Msg/<span>");
            }
            else //goes to this is dates are correct
            {
                validatedState = true;
                count += 2;
                txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
        }
//END IF VALIDATE ENTRY

//CONFIRMS ALL ARE CORRECT
        if (count == 5 && validatedState == true)
        {
            Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
            Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
            Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
            Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
            Response.Redirect("frmPersonnelVerified.aspx");
            //sends to other page
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(Msg);
        }
//ENDS CONFIRMATION OF CORRECT DATA


    }//end Function: private void BtnSubmit_click...

}[![Current Error Response][1]][1]
```

Comment: You might consider using ASP.NET validation controls, rather than rolling your own. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx

Comment: Hi, given that it seems you are using WebForms, I recommend you use Validation Controls, there's a Validation Summary that automatically show the warning messages that you need. Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: If you still want to use this approach you can use [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of '\r\n'

Comment: Are you sure adding `\r\n` didn't work? I only see it in your code once, so maybe it did display on two lines but the width of the window made it hard to tell, and then all the text after that *don't* have `\r\n` right now so they would still be in "paragraph form" as you say. And I agree with @AlenaKastsiukavets to use `Environment.NewLine`, but on Windows that simply returns `\r\n` anyway,so if you are having problems with `\r\n` then I doubt using `Environment.NewLine` will fix it, but I would still use it.

Comment: @Alena Kastsiukavets Oh, Alena sorry, I did try that--though I wonder if I used it right because I had the same thing occur where it just spat out a paragraph of errors instead of line by line. Would have been like so : Msg = Msg + "Text" + Environment.NewLine;   ?

Comment: As for the validation controls this is a homework assignment and I assume that before I get to those my professor wants me to learn manually? Not sure, but I would prefer to stick to the requirements for now. Though, I will be looking to those because they sound very interesting, just not what the professor asked for.

Comment: If you're generating HTML it's quite possible that neither `"\r\n"` nor `Environment.NewLine` will work. However, adding `"<br/>"` should do it.

Comment: @JimMischel, agree, only noticed that `Response.Write` is used)

Comment: @Quantic  You will not see them in the code above, I tried it prior to the other options you see now. I tried \r\n in two ways:  Msg = Msg + "Text goes here \r\n"; and Msg = Msg + "Text" + "\r\n"; Neither worked unfortunately.

Comment: @JimMischel Will try this, thank you :)

Comment: @JimMischel It worked :) Thank you very much for your assistance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the built in validation methods are not sufficient or efficient enough or somehow insecure in some way or for any other reason desire to then I encourage you to encapsulate your validation within a delegate which can be invoked when required for example:

`bool Invalidate(Session session)`

Determine the logic required in the function such as if the session has the member you require to validate or otherwise.

If the result is true the Session is not valid otherwise it is.

Derive this work flow to encapsulate your requirements further.

`bool InvalidateWorkFlowXYZ(Session session)`

Further the pattern may be defined within an `interface` which will allow you to define any additional parameters you desire. i.e.

`public interface IWorkFlow
        {
            System.Action<bool> Invalidate { get; }
        }`

This will allow you to decouple the view logic with the validation logic and not have to deal with the existing mechanisms or their API paradigms.

Reguards

Comment: Okay, so my homework assignment is kind of pushing me towards doing things on my own--however, I've never really used Validation methods so I can't be sure how I feel about them yet. Though from what I've gathered so far they seem to be rather useful. But, I do have a habit of leaning towards writing things out on my own so I might just follow this advice in my future assignments. Thanks for the time you spent explaining it as well.

Comment: Thanks, and please don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted if you think this is the answer was the solution.