# RegEx for time not working

Tags: regex

I am trying to generate a specific regex to validate time between 7:30 and 16:30 with half an hour difference. e.g

7:30, 8:00,8:30 , ..... 16:30

for this I am using pattern below but its not working I have tested my regex on [Regex](http://regexr.com/) but its not matching other than the first two characters.

```
^0[7-9]|1[0-6]:[0|3]0$
```

Comment: This type of match doesn't require regular expressions... See Split.

Comment: @Jay: it is validation, not extracting hours and minutes from the string.

Comment: So what? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468498/adding-to-a-message-for-various-errors-on-form/38468636#38468636

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the part before `:` inside brackets.

```
^(0[7-9]|1[0-6]):[03]0$
```

or

> I am trying to generate a specific regex to validate time between 7:30 and 16:30

```
^(?:07:30|(0[8-9]|1[0-6]):[03]0)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wO7rX5/2)

Comment: it takes into account 07:00 as well.

Comment: @MehvishFaisal see my second answer.